# How do I gain access to the persistance store file of my app on the simulator?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

How do I gain access to the persistance store file of my app on the simulator?

I know how to get it off my device but not the simulator

Comment: ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator

Comment: There is no iphone simulator folder on my machine in that dir

Comment: Make sure you have hidden files set as visible.  This widget makes it easy.  http://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/developer/hiddenfiles.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/(iOS version #)/Applications/, there will be a folder with a hex ID for every app containing the .app package and the directories Documents, Library, and tmp.

Note that it's in "~/Library" not "/Library".